# Checking string for conditions

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a string, and I want to check a lot of conditions on this string. For example:

1. It is of size x
2. Has no white spaces
3. The last letter is a numeric character

All of the conditions from 1-3
It can be done in a regular standard way in a function (if this and that etc')

But... How would I do that in one line in a good python style way?

Comment: There are certainly other ways to do it, but I don't think anything will be as clear as the "if this and that etc."

Comment: Just use a regex, `\S{x-1}\d$`, (replacing x-1 with the actual number)

Comment: Now you have 2 problems.

Comment: @mayhewr Do enlighten us. Is there a justification to this vitriol against regexes besides "I don't understand them"?

Comment: To me, regex, while totally awesome, powerful, and admittedly appropriate in OP's situation, is not the "pythonic" way of solving this problem, which is what OP asked for.  The "pythonic" way is what @mgilson said IMO.  Also, I think it's funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be more complicated than it's worth, but you can check all of those conditions with a regular expression.

For example, if the size you wanted was 8 characters, you could use the following to check all three conditions:

```
if re.match(r'\S{7}\d$', text):
    print 'all conditions match'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a simple `if` condition with `any`:

```
s='fdsfgsgsfds9'
if len(s)==7 and not any(c.isspace() for c in s) and s[-1].isdigit():
    pass
```

Comment: +1 for the non-regex solution that is far more readable for all users, especially those not regex-inclined.

Comment: I would write this as `if len(s) == 7 and not any(c.isspace() for c in s) and s[-1].isdigit()`: somewhat easier to read, I think.

Comment: @DSM thanks for teaching me about `any()`,solution edited. :)

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use a regular expression (assuming an `x` of 10):

```
if re.match(r"\S{10}(?<=\d)$", mystring):
    # Success!
```

Comment: @PaulBeckingham: No, it isn't. You do know about lookaround assertions?

Comment: 10 + the digit, so your example is for 11, not 10.

Comment: @PaulBeckingham That's a zero-width assertion.

Comment: Why not change this to use a format string and use any number.  This would be valid, right? ``"\\S{%d}(?<=\\d)$" % x`` (not sure if you can do this with raw string)

Comment: @Jeff: Good idea. And yes, it also works with a raw string: `re.match(r"\S{%d}(?<=\d)$" % x, mystring)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
import re
def test(s):
    return len(s)>=x and re.match("^\S*\d$", s)
```

This will test whether the string has length of at least `x` and that it is a sequence of non-space-characters followed by a digit character at the end.